# After my suspension period, my reputation was not returned

Tags: support, reputation, account-suspension

On Stack Overflow, I have a suspension period of 7 days which ends today. But my actual reputation has not been returned to me as one of the moderators said it would. I have a message like this by @Andrew Barber:

> Once your suspension period is over, you will be returned to your
>   correct reputation level, minus the votes from the accounts which have
>   been deleted. At that time, you are more than welcome to return, and
>   continue contributing your knowledge, and gaining legitimate
>   reputation points. Just please keep our rules in mind when you do.
>
> Regards
>
> Andrew Barber, Stack Overflow moderator

Can any moderator here help me or tell me what the rules are of getting back my reputation?

How can I get the attention of a moderator so that they can resolve my problem?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Reputation is recalculated literally at the same time as the suspension is lifted:

> [image]

However, suspensions are cleared once an hour. The scheduler might not run exactly when your suspension is scheduled to expire, which gives the illusion of a delay between suspension expiration and a reputation recalc.

An easy way to think about this is "Does the user profile still show the suspension banner? If yes, the suspension is still in effect.".

Answer (score 19):

When your suspension period is over it takes some time to calculate your reputation points. Because the reputation calculation script at interval of some time.

When they calculate your points it will be credited to you. It will be credited within 1 day of your suspension period is over.

Check your profile. You just get credited 369 points.

Comment: @Adam Lear my account was suspended last year, but i didn't get my points back. can i raise any requsets on this to anyone?