# Cannot send a message to moderator

Tags: support, moderator-messages

I am trying to send a message to the moderators because the last message that was sent was from me. The message I see is

> "you cannot post an additional message until a moderator has
>   responded"

I had a follow up question. The moderator said "Your reputation is set to 1 for the duration of your suspension. It'll be restored to your proper reputation once the suspension is over.". I responded "Alright, thank you". **But because I responded already, I could not send any sort of follow up today.** My suspension is over and my rep on SO is still 1.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: "the last message that was sent was from me," and "you cannot post an additional message until a moderator has responded." I don't see the problem here.

Comment: Well I had a follow up question. The moderator said "Your reputation is set to 1 for the duration of your suspension. It'll be restored to your proper reputation once the suspension is over.". My suspension is over and my rep on SO is still 1

Comment: As far as I can see, your rep has been restored to normal on SO. Perhaps it was a caching issue. [See this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179977).

Comment: I think someone just fixed it for me.

Comment: I recommend holding down-votes on this, unless you know some history, this isn't exactly intuitive or easy to search for.

Comment: @Tim while I agree, the message is in plain English, it's pretty hard to miss what it means.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well, that's great, if you're conversationally fluent and _not_ enraged at what you honestly perceive to be an injustice. When you get mad or don't understand what's happening to you, well .. We're working on the whole system.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: The mod responded last week with the answer to wait until suspension was over to have rep restored. I responded "Alright, thank you". But because i responded already, I could not send any sort of follow up today.

Comment: @Bijan I'm headed out for the day (typing as I pack up), I will review stuff and get back to you tomorrow. Thanks for bringing this up.

Comment: @TimPost: My problem is resolved. I guess a moderator saw this and fixed the issue. Thank you though

Comment: @Tim sorry but I can't see how this can be more clear. I held my guns on this, but honestly think people can spend few more seconds to actually read and try to understand the meaning of the various messages they see. And the OP here doesn't sound enraged. Anyway, as he said in above comments, the issue is resolved, took a while for the reputation to be recalculated after suspension was over.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'd love, for just a _day_ to live in the world where you do, where intelligent people consistently reach logical and constructive conclusions :) You're _not_ wrong, it's just that pesky human nature thing.

Comment: @Tim flight ticket on its way! But if anything, I'd love, for just a day, to be as tolerant as you. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A mod has to respond because so many contacted by a moderator continuously reply with something like this:

> Eat my big, orange traffic cone, or I will continue to bang my head on your bridges.

It also (unfortunately) sometimes looks like this:

> I will kill your whole f**king family you nazi f*** and don't think I won't or can't you kitten-eating asshat

Mods get notified of these replies, and there's very little signal to be gained that indicates that you aren't an armchair serial killer *except* a mod finding your reply sane enough to reply to. Mods are also volunteers, and quite busy.

It's not a perfect system, which is why you can [contact us directly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) if you have any questions, concerns, follow-ups or complaints about your interaction with a moderator on any of our sites.

I've personally experienced death threats after messaging people, so have others. Our world is the way it is and while we all wish it could be better, you're welcome to just use the work-around in cases where you forgot to add something important and / or want someone to review your case.

Comment: It is worth noting that the last time I sent that message, the mod in question did *not* deny eating kittens.

Comment: We have bridges?  I was never told about this.

Comment: [the internet in meme flavor](http://cdn.meme.am/instances/55674492.jpg)