# After suspension is over reputation hasn't been recalculated

Tags: bug, status-norepro, reputation, account-suspension

I had a suspension for a couple of days for some sock puppet account, it said that my reputation will back to normal after suspension, but is hasn't! It is still 1.

Comment: Are you sure that your rep was more than 1 (subtracted the sockpuppet upvotes) before? You lost 347 rep, because of removal of that sock account I guess.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes, see the reputation graph and tab, looks like OP had around 900.

Comment: TL;DR - you were still suspended, the banner disappears before the suspension is really over. No bug here.

Comment: @Oded this is reproduced by looking on profiles of users who were suspended up to an hour ago, see dupe.

Comment: Your reputation isn't 1 anywhere. Couldn't see anything otherwise.

Comment: @Oded it was 1 for about 40 minutes, without any suspension notice.

Comment: @Oded I also saw it as 1 at the time the question was asked, although it's not 1 anymore.  Sounds like it could just be caching though.

Comment: @Servy not caching, two different jobs running on different intervals. One job just removes the suspension banner, one job actually lift the suspension.

Comment: More likely - the scheduled job ran when it ran... Automatic reputation recalcs can take a while.

Comment: @Oded no, see [Adam's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/257631/152859).

Comment: @animuson can you also please remove the wrong tag? This can be "reproduced" easily, as I tried to explain in comments before.

Answer (score 3):

It just took some time (about half an hour) for your reputation to recalculate.

I figure it has now, because your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/3949600/user3260606?tab=accounts) doesn't have any one-rep accounts.

Comment: yes it took some times , definitely longer than a few hours .

Comment: @aeid I doubt it. More likely you posted this "bug" report few minutes after the suspension banner was gone, as said in the dupe answer it takes up to one hour for the actual lift to be executed.